# python - counting algorithm solving using "bitwise or of x and y"

Tags: python

I am analyzing a solution to the counting exercise from Codility ([Frog_river_one](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/4-counting_elements/frog_river_one/)). 
Most of the solutions I have seen are based on looping through the positions and values of the given array. One of the solutions I came across seems to tackle this problem differently.

I recognize that the "bitwise or of x and y" was used there however I don't understand the logic of the solution. Especially the part `checker=checker| 1<<(A[x]-1)` 
Can anybody explain please?

The problem

> A small frog wants to get to the other side of a river. The frog is
>   currently located at position 0, and wants to get to position X.
>   Leaves fall from a tree onto the surface of the river. You are given a
>   non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers representing
>   the falling leaves. A[K] represents the position where one leaf falls
>   at time K, measured in minutes. The goal is to find the earliest time
>   when the frog can jump to the other side of the river. The frog can
>   cross only when leaves appear at every position across the river from
>   1 to X.

[The solution](https://codesays.com/2014/solution-to-frog-river-one-by-codility/)

```
A= [1,3,1,4,2,3,5,4]

def solution(X, A):
    checker=0
    final_val=pow(2,5)-1
    for x in range(len(A)):
        checker=checker| 1<<(A[x]-1)

        if(checker==final_val):
            return x
    return -1
```

Comment: Your questions become more interesting ))).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the method `solution` should be changed slightly to:

```
def solution(X,A):
    checker = 0
    final_val = pow(2,X) - 1
    for x in range(len(A)):
        checker = checker | 1 << (A[x] - 1)

        if(checker == final_val):
            return x
    return -1

A = [1,3,1,4,2,3,5,4]

print(solution(5,A))
```

The basic idea behind this algorithm is to make sure that all leaves have fallen on the river up to and including position `X` by using the bitwise operations and binary representation of the positions of the leaves.

In order to make this work you define `final_val` which is equal to `2^X -1`. In the case when `X` is `5`, `final_val` is `2^5 - 1 = 31`.

Then you iterate through list `A`.

This is the most interesting part.

```
checker = checker | 1 << (A[x] - 1)
```

You initialize `checker` as equal to `0`.

Then let's break down the expression above:

`1 << (A[x] - 1)` is the same as 2^(A[x] - 1). This operation shifts binary 1 to the left by `A[x] - 1' bits. This operation is done to make sure that the leave exists at position`A[x]`.

Then goes the `|` operator (`OR`). In this case this some sort of a `plus` operator but it does not add repetitive terms.

So let's go through the given example to show how it works.

```
x = 0: 

1 << A[0] - 1 which is 1 << 1 - 1
                       1 << 0
```

No shift. 1 remains 1.

```
checker = 0 | 1
```

The bitwise `|` gives 1.

So `checker` is now 1. This means that there is a leaf at position `1`.

```
x = 1:

1 << A[1] - 1 which is 1 << 3 - 1
                       1 << 2
```

So now 1 becomes 100 in binary. This means that there is a leaf at position `3`.

Then:

```
checker = 1 | 100
```

Actually it is `001 | 100` which gives `101`.

```
x = 2:

checker = 101 | 1 << 0
        = 101
```

Note here position `1` has already appeared, so it does not change the `checker` variable.

```
x = 3:

checker = 101 | 1 << 3
        = 101 | 1000
        = 0101 | 1000
        = 1101
```

Now `checker` is `1101`. This means that there is a leaf at position `4`.

```
x = 4:

checker = 1101 | 1 << 1
        = 1101 | 10
        = 1101 | 0010
        = 1111
```

This means that there is a leaf at position `2`.

```
x = 5:            

checker = 1111 | 1 << 4
        = 1111 | 10000
        = 01111 | 10000
        = 11111
```

This means that there is a leaf at position `5`.

But this is the position where the frog needs to get.

This is why there is a checking condition which compares `checker` with the `final_val` every iteration.

So we see that `11111` is equal to `final_val` (31 is 11111 in binary) and the algorithm returns the position of `5` which `6`.

Note that if some of the positions did not appear before 5, e.g. instead of `2` there was `1`, then algorithm would return -1 as there is no way for the frog to get to the position `5`.

Comment: ok,I got it thanks to your excellent explanation! basically the whole algorithm is based on the fact that a given binary number can be added only ones using the operation "|" . The loop runs through the time k and keeps adding the binary representation of corresponding leaf positions until the sum of all positions equals the required number representing the whole distance to hop over.

Comment: I am glad my explanation helped you ).